# How am I supposed to support GNOME on Wayland with SDL2?

Tags: sdl, sdl-2, gnome, wayland

GNOME has chosen to not support server-side decorations under Wayland. That's okay, but I'm making a game in SDL, and I'd like first-class Linux support, including supporting running natively in Wayland (with SDL_VIDEODRIVER=wayland) under the biggest desktop environments (including GNOME).

Currently, when I run my game with SDL_VIDEODRIVER=wayland, no decorations are drawn. How am I supposed to integrate with the rest of the system? What's the story for non-GTK/Qt applications in practice?

Comment: Are you running SDL from the latest HG checkouts or relying on your distro's binaries?

Answer (score 1):

The SDL2 developers are working on this right now: https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL/pull/4068 So while there isn't an easy solution as of now, the good news is that you'll probably not really need to do anything than wait a few more months and then just use latest SDL2.

In general, the situation for non-Qt/GTK stuff is like this:

GNOME is currently not willing to introduce the decoration code into GNOME's compositor Mutter mostly from what I can tell are technical reasons: GNOME's decorations are GTK+-based, but Mutter has apparently zero GTK+ code right now so it's apparently not as easy to integrate as one would hope.

So non-GTK/Qt applications have three options: 1. [they can manually implement it](https://github.com/mpv-player/mpv/pull/7186), or 2. they can use something like [libdecoration](https://github.com/christianrauch/SDL/tree/decoration) as SDL2 is apparently going to do, or 3. pull in GTK+ as a dependency purely for the window and decorations which e.g. Electron/Chromium uses it for. It seems like in the medium term at least, GNOME will not fix this so these are the only options I'm aware of.